# Finding GRASSBIN on Linux

Tags: python, grass-gis, linux

I am installing GRASS on linux. I have managed to download source code and compile and can now run `grass` from the command line to open GRASS and start a session. I am trying to run python scripts outside of the GUI, however, and keep encountering the same error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script: /bin/grass, set the right one using the GRASSBIN environm. variable
```

I have tried setting GRASSBIN to the output of `which grass` which also didnt work, and I have run the `grass --config path` command as outlined in these docs: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_existing_location

This still does not work. Please, what am I doing wrong? I am using Amazon Linux

EDIT:

grass is installed in $HOME
output of `which grass`: /usr/local/bin/grass78
have also tried setting GRASSBIN to $HOME/grass/bin.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

I have also set
export GISBASE=$HOME/grass
export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib
LOCATION is unset as this is the first time I am running script. The actual script doesnt do anything at the moment:

```
from grass_session import Session
from grass.script import core as gcore
from multiprocessing import Pool
# import grass.script as grass
# from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g

def main():


    print("working")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please post the output of: `which grass`,  the path to your GISDBASE and LOCATION, and the python script that you are running, which throws that error.

Comment: Ok have edited the question to include that information

Answer (score 1):

Following the "Working with GRASS without starting it explicity" that you linked to in your question, you need to set several variables in advance, before calling `from grass.script import core as gcore`:

```
# DATA
# Here set your path to grassdata (GRASS GIS database) directory
# Probably :
gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "grass")

# Specify (existing) location and mapset
# From your first startup of GRASS in an interactive session
location = "nc_spm_08"
mapset   = "user1"

grass7bin = "/usr/local/bin/grass78" # in your case
startcmd = [grass7bin, '--config', 'path']
p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: Cannot find GRASS GIS 7 start script (%s)" % startcmd
    sys.exit(-1)
gisbase = out.strip('\n\r')

# Set GISBASE environment variable
os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase
# the following not needed with trunk
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(gisbase, 'extrabin')
# add path to GRASS addons
home = os.path.expanduser("~")
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(home, '.grass7', 'addons', 'scripts')

# define GRASS-Python environment
gpydir = os.path.join(gisbase, "etc", "python")
sys.path.append(gpydir)

########### DATA
# Set GISDBASE environment variable
os.environ['GISDBASE'] = gisdb
```

Please take note that the above assumes you have already started GRASS once in the normal, interactive way, and setup a LOCATION and MAPSET.
If that is not clear, please refer to [this wiki page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/helptext.html) and any of the videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grass%20gis)