# GRASS paths in Python standalone from QGIS install

Tags: python, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin, grass.script

I am trying to access GRASS from Python (Spyder).

I have:

- Installed via `pip install grass-session`
- Started GRASS from OSGEO4W, loaded the mapset and location
- Started Spyder from Anaconda
- Tried to follow https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly with no success

Code:

```
import os

## grass78 --config
# C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.22.7/apps/grass/grass78

## possible GRASSBIN
# C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.7\apps\grass\grass78\bin

# set some common environmental variables, like:
os.environ.update(dict(GRASSBIN = r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.7\apps\grass\grass78\bin"))
grass7bin_win = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.7\bin\grass78.bat'


from grass_session import Session
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
```

errors:

> RuntimeError: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.7\apps\grass\grass78\bin, set the right one using the GRASSBIN environm. variable

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grass'

I think this is similar to [How to use GRASS GIS in Python standalone?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371729/how-to-use-grass-gis-in-python-standalone) and [Finding GRASSBIN on Linux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420247/finding-grassbin-on-linux) but  they're from standalone GRASS installations and I can't work it out still.

Any ideas on how to fix this?